# Reuse MongoClient in an Express app with routing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I'd like to reuse the MongoClient connection in my routes (I have seen that there are ways using the **old** connectivity however I'd like to use MongoClient and I'd also like to have a separate DB configuration file

app.js (snippet)

```
var route = require('route');
app.get("/", route.test);
```

dbconf.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongourl = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {
  if(err) console.log('Error connecting to ' + mongourl + ': ' + err);
  var coll = db.collection('testcollection');
});
```

route.js (snippet)

```
exports.test = function(req, res) {
  //i would like to use the connection created in dbconf.js here
}
```

Comment: I wrote an NPM module to do just that: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoconnect (it works as long as you only need to connect to one database)

Comment: possible duplicate of [node-mongodb-native: How can I share the db api object of the connection callback through my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863675/node-mongodb-native-how-can-i-share-the-db-api-object-of-the-connection-callbac)

Answer (score 1):

You could use promises. This way the connection will only be opened once, but you will be able to reuse the database object easily. A very basic version would look somehting like this:

database.js

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    Q = require('q');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var deferred = Q.defer();

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, database) {
  if (err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
    return;
  }
  deferred.resolve(database);
});

exports.connect = function() {
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

router.js

```
var database = require('./database');

exports.test = function(req, res) {
  database.connect().then(function(db) {
    var coll = db.collection('testcollection');
  });
};
```

Comment: This is not a good practice since it will initialize a connection to the Mongodb database in every request

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, although it doesn't use a separate dbconf.js file (I don't see the point to be honest as this way the app index will be as small as possible since routing is separated.):

./index.js:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    routes = require('./routes'),
    express = require('express')
    app = new express();
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {
    if ( err ) {
        // handle error
    }

    routes(app,db);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

./routes/index.js:

```
testHandler = require('./test');

var routes = function(app,db) {
    var testhandler = new testHandler(db);

    app.get('/',testhandler.index);
}

exports = module.exports = routes;
```

./routes/test.js:

```
var testHandler = function(db) {
    this.index = function(req,res) {
        db.collection('data').find().toArray(function(err,data) {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
}
exports = module.exports = testHandler;
```

Comment: In express 4.0 ,router middlewares has been introduced.it can be accessed as _app.use('/',routes)_ .
 In this case how can u pass the db object to the router middleware??Any idea?